# What does "factor out" mean in Shilov's definition of cofactors?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am working my way through Shilov's Linear Algebra for a more theoretical approach on the topic.

From my knowledge, the cofactor of an element $a_{ij}$ is the signed minor $(-1)^{i+j} M_{ij}$.

Shilov defined determinants with the equation

$$
D=\sum(-1)^{N(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)}a_{\alpha_11}\dots a_{\alpha_nn}.
$$

He proceeded to say that if we add up all terms containing $a_{ij}$ appearing on the RHS of the equation above and factor our $a_{ij}$ we get the cofactor of the element $a_{ij}$.

However, it seems that I do not understand what "factor out" means here since I get a completely different result when

1. removing all the terms with $a_{ij}$ or
2. simply factoring them out (like a product) which does not change the quantity at all.

The two methods I did does not equal the first definition regarding signed minors.

I can't find explanations of Shilov's cofactors, so far. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: If you factor out $a$ from $ax+ay+ah$ you get $x+y+h$. In other words divide by $a$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek thanks! I think I understood it now. Shilov meant to only consider the terms involving $a_{ij}$ for the cofactor, right? I was adding the terms that do not include $a_{ij}$. My mistake. Thanks a lot!